# From Portrait to Landscape mode issue

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm having issue with the rotation from portrait to landscape mode on my app that I'm working on right now. The app lunches ok but when i rotate my phone or emulator I'm experiencing the problem. [image: this is what happens when i rotate my phone] [[image: this is how it should be[2]]

This is the error that I get when rotate from one mode to another.

Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:402)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatColorStateListInflater.inflate(AppCompatColorStateListInflater.java:114)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatColorStateListInflater.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatColorStateListInflater.java:88)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatColorStateListInflater.createFromXml(AppCompatColorStateListInflater.java:67)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:116)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:74)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:170)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.onSetTextAppearance(AppCompatTextHelper.java:296)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:162)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat$TextViewCompatBaseImpl.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:155)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:476)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:634)
                                                                             at com.jovan.matetracker.LoginActivity$2.onTextChanged(LoginActivity.java:68)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8126)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4323)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4169)
                                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:85)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4144)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:4044)
                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14141)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(TextInputLayout.java:1040)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3089)
                                                                             at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14119)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2220)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1086)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1027)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1174)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4378)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may be occuring when there is a change in state in the Activity lifecycle. When you change the orientation, landscape to portrait or vise versa, the Activity is destroyed and created again.

More specifically, when orientation change occurs, the method `onDestroy()` is called.

Take a look at the methods where your Layout Inflater is being manipulated/receiving the reference.

Comment: Looks like that the focus on the AppCompatEditText is being set of true so i tried to reset it to be false again but  my method doesn't work. Here is what i tried to do. 



`@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        username.setOnFocusChangeListener(new 
 View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (username.hasFocus() && (username.getText().length() == 0)) {
                    username.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
}`